how can i deal this error in the progress of Compiling?
after gmake command:
[saicma@me]$ gmake Makefile
mpif90 -I/include   -I/path/to/Par  -I/path/to/mod  -I/path/to/include -c -o /path/to/*.o /path/to/*.f
pgi-f95-lin64: LICENSE MANAGER PROBLEM: Cannot find license file.
 The license files (or license server system network addresses) attempted are 
listed below.  Use LM_LICENSE_FILE to use a different license file,
 or contact your software provider for a license file.
Feature:       pgi-f95-lin64
Filename:      /pkg/pgi/license.dat
License path:  /pkg/pgi/license.dat:
FlexNet Licensing error:-1,359.  System Error: 2 "No such file or directory"
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
gmake: *** [/path/to/*.o] Error 2


and I found a license.info in /pkg/pgi. Here is part of the content of it.
There are two ways to obtain a license key for the PGI compilers and tools:

1. Invoke PGI's license generation tool

   /pkg/pgi/linux86-64/14.10/bin/pgi_license_tool

2. Login to your PGI account on www.pgroup.com.  The hostid information for
   this computer is shown below, and is also in the file /pkg/pgi/license.info.

   Place your license key in the file /pkg/pgi/license.dat.
...
...

after enter the path of /pkg/pgi/linux86-64/14.10/bin and run ./pgi_license_tool.
there is the errors:
[saicma@me bin]$ ./pgi_license_tool
./pgi_license_tool: /pkg/pgi/linux86-64/14.10/bin/lmutil: /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3: bad ELF interpre:No such file or directory

The FLEXlm hostid for this computer is empty.  License keys cannot be 
created.  Please go to http://www.pgroup.com/support/faq.htm for more
details on licensing your PGI product.


The PGI license tool can be re-started by running the script located at
/pkg/pgi/linux86-64/14.10/bin/pgi_license_tool.

/bin/rm: cannot remove `/pkg/pgi/license.info': Permission denied
./pgi_license_tool: line 64: /pkg/pgi/license.info: Permission denied

after enter the url(http://www.pgroup.com/support/faq.htm), and I found the solution.
Why am I seeing the error '$PGI/linux86-64/*.*/bin/lmutil: No such file or directory'?
PGI compilers use FlexNet for license management, which requires your system provide the Linux Standard Base (LSB) ld linker/loader helper library
/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 or a symlink to an equivalent such as ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. For most distributions one of the following commands typically fixes the
problem:
sudo ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
- or -
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
If the problem persists, try installing the full LSB package for your distribution.
Recheck lmutil again and see if things work. If not, try reinstalling the PGI compilers.

the picture of the solution
but i don't have the su passwd to run this command
"sudo ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3". what should i do?
try to let the gmake command succesfully.

because $LM_LICENSE_FILE is empty, loading the correspond module can deal with the error. like module load .

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
